# App launched from Xcode always starting behind all other apps?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

A specific project I've been working on for a while now all of a sudden would display the application - when launched via '**Run**' from Xcode 4 - *behind* all other running apps, in particular behind the Xcode IDE.

This happen regardless of the *Debug Workflow* setting. Changing it to *Xcode always behind* only causes Xcode to be hidden behind the other running apps as well. Very weird.

I couldn't find a scheme setting changing the app's behaviour, deleting all from the build folder had no effect either. Launching the app directly via Finder works just fine and brings it to the front.

**Edit #1:**

Deleting the app's prefs, user and system caches, the general clean using Onyx didn't help at all - 
of all apps this particular one keeps launching behind all other running apps.

Clueless.

Comment: Me too. No idea how to fix this.

Comment: Uh! At least I'm not imagining this - lol. Which Xcode version on your box? It's 4.2 here..

Comment: I'm on Xcode 4.6.3. I haven't seen this issue lately. Is the issue specific to a particular build target? If you duplicate the target, is it still present?

Comment: Just switched to 10.8 and the latest 4.x release, will keep reporting if the problem persists